# spacing with wedge and bigwedge with bigger index

Tags: spacing, amsmath

I have this math code:

```
\[
\bigwedge_{i,j \in \underline{n},\atop { i \neq j,\atop k,l \in \underline{|\sigma|}}} x_{i,k} \neq x_{j,l} \wedge
\bigwedge_{i \in \underline{n},\atop k \in \underline{|\sigma|-1}} x_{i,k+1} = x_{i,k} + 1 \wedge
\bigwedge_{i \in \underline{n},\atop k \in \underline{|\sigma|}} Q_{\sigma_k} x_{i,k}
\]
```

The vertical space around `\bigwedge` is quite huge and it looks a bit odd. I would like to have the "content" of the `\bigwedge` (e.g. `x_{i,k}\neq...`) much more close to it, then maybe the `\wedge` slightly more separated from the content and more close to the next `\bigwedge`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can decrease the spacing around the `\bigwedge` by putting the subscripts in the `\mathclap` command from the [mathtools](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package.  This puts its argument in a zero-width box which is centred at the desired location.  This also has the effect of putting the `\wedge` nearer the `\bigwedge`.  If you want it nearer still then there's probably a better way than just using negative spacing (`\!`) but certainly that does do the trick.

(I suspect that if the symbols weren't such funny shapes then that space between `\wedge` and `\bigwedge` wouldn't be so noticeable.)

[image: wedges]

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
\bigwedge_{i,j \in \underline{n},\atop { i \neq j,\atop k,l \in \underline{|\sigma|}}} x_{i,k} \neq x_{j,l} \wedge
\bigwedge_{i \in \underline{n},\atop k \in \underline{|\sigma|-1}} x_{i,k+1} = x_{i,k} + 1 \wedge
\bigwedge_{i \in \underline{n},\atop k \in \underline{|\sigma|}} Q_{\sigma_k} x_{i,k}
\]

\[
\bigwedge_{\mathclap{i,j \in \underline{n},\atop { i \neq j,\atop k,l \in \underline{|\sigma|}}}} x_{i,k} \neq x_{j,l} \wedge
\bigwedge_{\mathclap{i \in \underline{n},\atop k \in \underline{|\sigma|-1}}} x_{i,k+1} = x_{i,k} + 1 \wedge
\bigwedge_{\mathclap{i \in \underline{n},\atop k \in \underline{|\sigma|}}} Q_{\sigma_k} x_{i,k}
\]

\[
\bigwedge_{\mathclap{i,j \in \underline{n},\atop { i \neq j,\atop k,l \in \underline{|\sigma|}}}} x_{i,k} \neq x_{j,l} \wedge
\bigwedge_{\mathclap{i \in \underline{n},\atop k \in \underline{|\sigma|-1}}} x_{i,k+1} = x_{i,k} + 1 \wedge\!\!
\bigwedge_{\mathclap{i \in \underline{n},\atop k \in \underline{|\sigma|}}} Q_{\sigma_k} x_{i,k}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also hide the width of the subscripts, which has more or less the same effect as mathclap, I suppose:

```
$$
  \let\hw=\hidewidth
  \let\ul=\underline
  \bigwedge_{\hw i,j\in\ul n,\hw\atop{\hw i\neq j\hw\atop\hw k,l\in\ul{|\sigma|}\hw}}
    x_{i,k}\neq x_{j,l}\wedge
    \bigwedge_{\hw i\in\ul n,\hw\atop\hw k\in\ul{|\sigma|-1}\hw}
    x_{i,k+1}=x_{i,k}+1\wedge\bigwedge_{\hw i\in\ul n,\hw\atop\hw k\in\ul{|\sigma|}\hw}
    Q_{\sigma_k} x_{i,k}
$$
\bye
```

[image: hidewidth]